# What should I watch out for in a 3d artist's portfolio?

Tags: 3d-modeling, hiring

I'm looking to hire a freelancer to help with 3d modeling. I've thought up a few qualifiers so far:

- Is their topology okay for animation?
- Have they demonstrated the technical capabilities necessary for my project? (Have they baked normals, AO maps, etc.)
- Have they shown an ability to execute from conceptual drawings?

Are there any massively important things I should watch out for that I haven't included?

Any red flags I should be aware of, like making sure the work isn't plagiarized?

**Note**

I'm specifically talking about reviewing portfolio content, before interviewing them. I'm looking for things I can say yes or no to, or that I might want to question them on further in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for imagination, creativity, ability to work with a team, from where he gets inspiration, ability to schetch out a quick example of an idea... there are a lot of things to take in consideration when hiring an artist.

Comment: The [21st century skills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21st_century_skills) should be a good framework.

Comment: How might those things be conveyed in a _portfolio_?